# Why wont my JSON.stringify() work with localstorage.setItem()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, local-storage

I have an object pulled from a form on my page. I push this object into an array.

```
var postObj = {title:$('input').val(),body:$('textarea').val()}
postArray.push(postObj);
localstorage.setItem("posts", JSON.stringify(postArray));
```

However, I'm just getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: Localstorage is not defined`.

In the console I'm getting these responses from testing.

```
postObj
Object {title: "title", body: "dog"}
postArray
[
Object
body: "dog"
title: "title"
__proto__: Object
]
JSON.stringify(postArray);
"[{"title":"title","body":"dog"}]"
```

Most responses I've found to similar questions are saying to use `JSON.stringify(array)`. I don't know why when I use `JSON.stringify` as the data parameter of `.setItem` it is not working.

Comment: This looks like a case where `Localstorage` is either not yet defined, but it is defined after this script runs, so it does look like it is defined when you later check it, or it is always defined, but not in the scope of the function.

Comment: you should accept an answer to close out the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a typo, should be:

`window.localStorage // note the camelCase name`

Comment: Thank you. It was simply a typo. localStorage with a capital stringified the array.

Comment: the best and worst kind of bug